# How to support user-generated Model attributes (Rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has a User model, and a Game model. I want each user to be able to add their own personal set of Game attributes (that are only available/visible to them) aside from the ones I already have predefined.

What's the most 'Rails' way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll store per-user settings in the join table between `User` and `Game` and then your association between those two models will be a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) - meaning that you'll have a join model giving you access to the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use serialization:

Advantages:

- it's much flexible and built in
- you can store data the way you want (even your custom class)

Drawback:

- it would be hard to get your data back from database if you finally change your web framework.

[More doc see here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).